# Redux causing infinite refresh loop

Tags: reactjs, loops, redux, refresh

I'm pretty new to Redux, but am trying to add it to my existing project and am getting an infinite refresh loop back to my /login page. I don't see an immediate error and can't locate where the issue might be coming from. I think the loop might be coming from the render in App.js that pulls in the Login component, but can't seem to pinpoint it. I'd really appreciate any help with this one!

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import MuiThemeProvider from '@material-ui/core/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import createMuiTheme from '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme';
import themeFile from './util/theme';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';

// Redux
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './redux/store';


// Components
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import AuthRoute from './util/AuthRoute';

// Pages
import home from './pages/home';
import login from './pages/login';
import signup from './pages/signup';


const theme = createMuiTheme(themeFile);

let authenticated;
const token = localStorage.FBIdToken;

if(token){
  const decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
  if(decodedToken.exp * 1000 < Date.now()){
    window.location.href='/login'
    authenticated = false;
  } else {
    authenticated = true;
  };
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
      <Navbar/>
        <div className="container">
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={home}/>
          <AuthRoute exact path="/login" component={login} authenticated={authenticated}/>
          <AuthRoute exact path="/signup" component={signup} authenticated={authenticated}/>
        </Switch>
        </div>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

Login page:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import withStyles from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import AppIcon from '../images/micrologo.png'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

//MUI Stuff
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button'
import CircularProgress from '@material-ui/core/CircularProgress'

//Redux stuff
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { loginUser } from '../redux/actions/userActions';

const styles = (theme) => ({
    ...theme.spreadThis
})


class login extends Component {
    
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            errors: {}
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
       if(nextProps.UI.errors){
           this.setState({ errors: nextProps.UI.errors })
       }
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const userData = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        };
        this.props.loginUser(userData, this.props.history)
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value
        })
    }

    render() {
        const { classes, UI: { loading } } = this.props;
        const { errors } = this.state;

        return (
            <Grid container className={classes.form}>
                <Grid item sm/>
                <Grid item sm>
                    <img src={AppIcon} alt="micrologo" className={classes.image}/>
                    <Typography variant="h3" className={classes.pageTitle}>
                        Login
                    </Typography>
                    <form noValidate onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <TextField 
                        id="email" 
                        name="email" 
                        type="email" 
                        label="Email" 
                        className={classes.textField}
                        helperText={errors.email}
                        error={errors.email ? true : false}
                        value={this.state.email} 
                        onChange={this.handleChange} 
                        fullWidth 
                        />
                     <TextField 
                        id="password" 
                        name="password" 
                        type="password" 
                        label="Password" 
                        className={classes.textField}
                        helperText={errors.password}
                        error={errors.password ? true : false}
                        value={this.state.password} 
                        onChange={this.handleChange} 
                        fullWidth 
                        />
                    {errors.general && (
                        <Typography variant="body2" className={classes.customError}>
                            {errors.general}
                        </Typography>
                    )}
                    <Button 
                    type="submit" 
                    variant="contained" 
                    color="primary" 
                    className={classes.button}
                    disabled={loading}
                    >
                        Login
                        {loading && (
                            <CircularProgress size={30} className={classes.progress}/>
                        )}
                    </Button>
                    <br />
                    <small>Don't have an account? Sign up <Link to="/signup">here</Link>
                    </small>
                    </form>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item sm/>
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}

login.propTypes = {
    classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    loginUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    user: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    UI: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    user: state.user,
    UI: state.UI
});

const mapActionsToProps = {
    loginUser
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionsToProps)(withStyles(styles)(login));
```

User Details:

```
import { SET_USER, SET_ERRORS, CLEAR_ERRORS, LOADING_UI } from '../type';
import axios from 'axios'

export const loginUser = (userData, history) => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: LOADING_UI}); 
    axios
    .post('/login', userData)
    .then((res) => {
        const FBIdToken = `Bearer ${res.data.token}`;
        localStorage.setItem('FBIdToken', FBIdToken);
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = FBIdToken;
        dispatch(getUserData());
        dispatch({ type: CLEAR_ERRORS });
        history.push('/');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
       dispatch({ 
           type: SET_ERRORS,
           payload: err.response.data
       })
    })
}

export const getUserData = () => (dispatch) => {
    axios.get('/user')
        .then((res) => {
            dispatch({
                type: SET_USER,
                payload: res.data
            })
        })
        .catch((err) => 
            console.log(err)
        )
}
```

EDIT: After making changes to my User Actions file that references my User Reducer, could it possibly be something to do with the User Reducer code?

```
import { SET_USER, SET_ERRORS, CLEAR_ERRORS, LOADING_UI, SET_AUTHENTICATED, SET_UNAUTHENTICATED } from '../type';

const initialState = {
    authenticated: false,
    credentials: {},
    likes: [],
    notifications: []
};

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case SET_AUTHENTICATED:
            return {
                ...state,
                authenticated: true
            };
        case SET_UNAUTHENTICATED:
            return initialState
        case SET_USER:
            return {
                authenticated: true,
                ...action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: Adding copy > copy fetch code from network tab:

```
fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
    "if-none-match": "W/\"717-3FVndTj2FHm3TgZjXTrLARSY62Q\"",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1"
  },
  "referrer": "http://localhost:3000/login",
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": null,
  "method": "GET",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "omit"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
export const loginUser = (userData, history) => (
  dispatch
) => {
  dispatch({ type: LOADING_UI });
  axios
    .post("/login", userData)
    .then((res) => {
      const FBIdToken = `Bearer ${res.data.token}`;
      localStorage.setItem("FBIdToken", FBIdToken);
      axios.defaults.headers.common[
        "Authorization"
      ] = FBIdToken;
      //wait for getUserData to finish
      return getUserData()(dispatch);
    })
    .then(() => {
      //getUserData is finished
      dispatch({ type: CLEAR_ERRORS });
      history.push("/");
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      dispatch({
        type: SET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data,
      });
    });
};

export const getUserData = () => (dispatch) => {
  //return a promise so loginUser action can wait for
  //  it to finish
  return axios.get("/user").then((res) => {
    dispatch({
      type: SET_USER,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  });
  //if you catch it then the catch that set errors is
  //  pointless
  // .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for your suggestions! This logic makes a ton of sense, thank you for that. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same issue. This time, though, I got a Proxy Error: Proxy error: Could not proxy request /screams from localhost:3000 to https://us-central1-microaudio.cloudfunctions.net/api.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).
Here is the proxy declaration in my package.json file: 

  "proxy": "https://us-central1-microaudio.cloudfunctions.net/api",
  "secure": false

Comment: Could it be something from my User Reducer, perhaps?

Comment: @mkg3016 In the network tab you can right click the failing request and select copy => copy as fetch. Then add the code to your question (if it doesn't have secret tokens) and you can have a look at what it is that fails in the request. You can replace the url with url that webpack would proxy to and make the request directly to see what the problem is.

Comment: Hi, I've updated my post with the copy => copy as fetch code, but I'm sorry I'm not sure where exactly the request is failing (is it the null body?). How would I go about replacing the URL with the proxy, would that be in my package.json file? Thanks again, I'm still new and trying to learn! Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @mkg3016 I see 2 problems with the fetch code. First I can see method is `GET` but in your question the code does: `axios.post('/login', userData)` the second problem is that the body of the request is null but that is also impossible with the code posted in your question.

Comment: I solved the issue, and think I found where it was coming from. In my app.js, I was rerouting to /login prior to setting authentication to false, so I believe it just kept failing and re-routing. I switched the order so that it runs authenticated = false, then window.location.href='/login', and now and it worked.